# Angular - ArrayBuffer Image slow down the application

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rest, arraybuffer

I'm loading an `arrayBuffer` image from a REST service and the image slow down the application when displayed, is there any better way of doing this?

HTML:

```
<img (click)="previewPlaneringskarta()" class="planeringskarta" [src]="arrayBufferToBase64(planeringskarta)" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='/assets/img/notfound.png'"/>
```

TypeScript:

```
arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    let binary = '';
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    const len = bytes.byteLength;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
  
    const imageSrc = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + window.btoa(binary);
  
    this.planeringskartaSrc = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageSrc);
  
    return this.planeringskartaSrc;
}
```

Comment: Don't bind a method to your [src] attribute. Do the conversion and bind only the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using method in template, then Angular will always reexecute all functions template in every change detection cycle to compare.

Try to create property and then bind it to `src` attribute:

HTML:

```
<img [src]="imgSource"/>
```

TypeScript:

```
imgSource;

setImg() {
    this.imgSource= this.arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
}
```